# Determine the constant (that is, the coefficient of $x^0$) in $ (3x^2 - \frac{2}{x})^{15}$

Tags: combinatorics

I've been doing coefficient extractions for a bit but I've hit a stump. I've tried changing around the formula but just can't get it. This is what I've tried so far:

$$ (3x^2 - \frac{2}{x})^{15}=\frac1{(3x^2 - \frac{2}{x})^{-15}}$$

Then I tried plugging it into $A(X) = (A_n)(X^n)$ the formal power series formula. Please help and thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.

Comment: It is good to see that you've said what you've tried, that is always good when it comes to asking a question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Using the binomial theorem:
$$
\left(3x^2-\frac2x\right)^{15}=\sum_{k=0}^{15}\binom{15}{k}\left(3x^2\right)^k\left(-\frac2x\right)^{15-k}
$$
Thus, we want to find the $k$ so that $2k-(15-k)=0$; i.e. $k=5$. Thus, we are interested in the term from the sum where $k=5$.

Comment: You missed the binomial coefficient. (I didn't downvote)

Comment: @taninamdar: thanks... fixed

Comment: Actually, I downvoted, inadvertently. Am using an unfamiliar touchscreen laptop, and accidents happen. Luckily I was able to correct in time.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: actually, since I had edited after your vote, you could have changed your vote anytime.

Comment: Thank you so much. I planned to wake up and find an answer but you responded so quick! Thank you thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Our expression is equal to
$$\frac{(3x^3-2)^{15}}{x^{15}}.$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\left(3x^2 - \frac2x\right)^{15} = \dfrac{1}{x^{15}}(3x^3-2)^{15}$$

Therefore, the coefficient of $x^0$ in the first expression = coefficient of $x^{15}$ in $(3x^3-2)^{15}$.

Expanding $(3x^3-2)^{15}$ using binomial theorem, the $x^{15}$ will be in $5$th term.

$i$th term of $(a+b)^n = {n\choose i}a^i b^{n-i}$

Therefore, $5$th term in $(3x^3-2)^{15} = {15\choose 5}(3x^3)^5 (-2)^{15-5}$.

Comment: I didn't explicitly give the term in question. It may or may not be too much (I believe this is a homework question, but I could be wrong) (+1)

Comment: @taninamdar can you please explain how you got the x^15 on the bottom. I usually have trouble manipulating formulas and would like to hear your logic and apply it to my future questions. Thank you!

Comment: @BrandyAu Take LCM $3x^2 + \frac{2}{x} = \frac{3x^3}{x}+\frac{2}{x} = \frac{(3x^3 + 2)^{15}}{x^{15}}$